# Importing, sorting and exporting lists

Tags: list-manipulation, export, import, sorting

I have several `TSV` lists (`.txt`) of something like 2000*2000 numerics (e.g. `1.8645`) to import (symmetric matrices), rearrange and sort them by each row. Finally the data should be exported. The lists are imported by using `Import` but what I've tried so far to manipulate the lists is not working.

An simplified example for a file to import looks like this. First I have to remove the 1st row and column.

```
0   1   2   3   4
1   0   2   7   1
2   2   0   8   5
3   7   8   0   9
4   1   5   9   0
```

Afterwards the data should look like this:

```
0   2   7   1
2   0   8   5
7   8   0   9
1   5   9   0
```

Then, the data should by sorted ascending by each row:

```
0   1   2   7
0   2   5   8
0   7   8   9
0   1   5   9
```

Finally this list is exported with `Export`.

This is what I wrote up to now:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
myFileNames = Take[FileNames["*txt"]];
lineStart = 2;
lineEnd = 5;
For[c = 1, c <= Length[myFileNames], c++,
  Data = {};
  aa = myFileNames[[c]];
  myImportData = Import[aa, "TSV"];
  Data = myImportData;
  (*delete 1st row and column*)
  For[cc = 1, cc <= lineEnd - lineStart + 1, cc++,
   Delete[Data, {1, cc}];
   ];
  For[cc = 1, cc <= lineEnd - lineStart + 1, cc++,
   Delete[Data, {cc, 1}];
   ];
  (*sort the data by each column*)
  For[cc = 1, cc <= lineEnd - lineStart , cc++,
   Sort[Data {cc, 1}];
   ];
  (*transpose the matrix to achive sorted rows*)
  Transpose[Data];
  (*export the data*)
  Export[ToString[aa] <> "_output.txt", Data, "TSV"];
  ];
```

For some reason even `Delete` is not working. My idea was to sort the columns and transpose the list to achieve the sorted rows.

If you know any good tutorial or something similar I'd really appreciate a hint where to find it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
names = FileNames["*.txt"];
Export[StringInsert[#, "_output", -5], 
   Sort /@ Import[#, "Table"][[2 ;;, 2 ;;]], "TSV"] & /@ names
```

Comment: Can you show a simple input/output ?

Comment: I worked on the example give by the OP and I got the same output.

Comment: Thanks alot. Even with the real data the code is working.I think I really have to improve my mathematica-skills. Do you have any suggestion how to learn to use mathematica in such way?

Comment: My pleasure to help. thanks for accepting the answer. you can find good information here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice and here:http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users